# How manage or clean deploy section in dproj files?

Tags: delphi

On saving project with only Win32 target platform in Delphi 10.1 Berlin and some previous versions of Delphi XE, I've got a .dproj file with added a big section  with many  items that having many  items for all platforms that Delphi potentially support.

How to prevent adding this garbage to .dproj by an IDE?

Comment: Open the .dproj file in a text editor and remove the unwanted content. IDE is going to keep adding this stuff back though, that's how it rolls. I'd commit the .dproj to revision control so that you can keep an eye on what the IDE is doing behind your back.

Comment: I have this question just because I have annoying differences and extra text in .dproj under my VCS. I want to switch off adding this section.

Comment: That's just life with the IDE. It's going to do that stuff. Nothing you can do about it. Keep watching the commits to the VCS and remove the crud when it gets added. Tedious I know.

Comment: @Nashev I feel your pain. The IDE keeps adding stuff to the .drpoj file and even worse, shuffling it around. But short of writing a program that cleans it up, there is nothing you can do about it. If you write such a program, I would be interested in it too.

Comment: @dummzeuch, the program seem to be pretty easy to make - just remove `<Deployment>` node. But how can it help? Where would you "hook" it?

Comment: @dummzeuch, XMLStarlet (https://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlstar/files/) can be used to remove Deployment tag from the project file, but who will call it on a project saves?..

Comment: It can be done, see Uwe Raabe's ProjectMagicion https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2018/05/17/keep-your-project-files-clean-with-project-magician/ and the older https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/18/dproj-changed-or-not-changed/ DprojNormalizer but I have no idea how it hooks into the IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe those sections are added by the profiledeployide*.bpl package.
Disable that package by adding an underscore to the corresponding Registry Data.

Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Embarcadero\BDS\21.0\Known IDE Packages

Name: $(BDS)\Bin\profiledeployide270.bpl

Data: _(Untitled)

[IDE Package To Disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY208.png)